# View loop with nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Working on the Domain view. I would like to loop through and list all Domains, all controls and any goals that are under those controls. I cannot figure out how to loop through the controls goals. Current solution just loops through all the goals, not just the goals that we connected to the Control

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :controls

class Control < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :domains
has_many :goals

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :control



  def index #domain controller
    @domains = Domain.all
    @controls = Control.all
    @goals = Goal.all
  end
```

domain index view

```
<% @domains.each do |domain| %>
<tr>
<td><%= domain.domainName %></td>
<% domain.controls.each do |control| %>
<td><%= control.controlName %></td>
<% @goals.each do |t| %>
<td>SG<%= t.goalsNumber %>, </td>
<% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Probably not the most efficient way to do this but it works for now

```html
<% domain.controls.each do |control| %>
  <td>
    <h3><%= control.controlName %></h3>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <% @goals.each do |goals| %>
    <% if goals.control.controlName==c ontrol.controlName %>
      <tr>
        <td>SG
          <%=g oals.goalsNumber %>
            <%=g oals.goalsName %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% else %>
        <% end %>
          <% end %>
            <% end %>
```